# PM2 on Windows logs error at NPM.CMD with Unexpected Token

Tags: pm2, strapi

I am trying to run the StrApi admin template on a Windows machine under pm2. I could start the ecosystem.config.js using `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` but the admin site doesn't load on a browser. Checking the `pm2 logs` shows error at **C:\PROGRAM FILES\NODEJS\NPM.CMD** with **SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'**.

I am sorry if I'm missing any steps.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing it the wrong way to configure.
The github [comment1](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2808#issuecomment-367352136) and [comment2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2808#issuecomment-434588396) solved the problem.

But now I have a new problem. After I run `pm2 start startscript.js`, it opens a new empty npm cmd window with just npm shown in header and my application loads on the browser until the empty npm command window is open, once it's closed automatically or by me manually, the site doesn't load anymore.

Please check out the issue [here](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2808#issuecomment-839559064).